# Not able to sign in Ubuntu One with "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" error

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I have clean installation of U11.10 (with updates).

f I run Ubuntu One client and try connect to my existent account, I get this error message:

> Method "CreateItem" with signature "a{sv}(oayay)b" on interface "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" doesn't exist

About this are some bug reports since U11.04, but I'm wondering, that such a key feature do not work at all in final release of U11.10.

I can live without Ubuntu One storage no more - so U11.10 is quite unusable for me!

What's going on ?
Where is the update to correct such important issue ?

**Please help**

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/874501) in gnome-keyring. The fix is already in upstream, and I have initiated a backport process. The fixed package is also available in the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-support).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a conversion error with your keyring that happened when you upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10. If you press ctrl+H while in your home directory, you can rename the folder named .gnome. This will create a new keyring for you, and Ubuntu One will work, but you'll have to enter your passwords once to store it in your new keyring. If you're interested, you can also try to convert your keyring manually, but that might require some more details.

Comment: No - as i wrote:  "I have clean installation of U11.10" - so no upgrade from anything, so no old keyrings, no (other) passwords, ...

Comment: You did not keep your home directory from another installation? That's strange. I've only seen this with upgrades or if you had a home directory from an earlier version.

Comment: In any case, please confirm that you _do not_ have a folder called .gnome in your home directory. You need to press ctrl+H to show hidden files. If you do have that directory, then rename it and see if it works.

Comment: 1. YES I did not keep HOME here. This is test instalation.

Comment: 2. YES I have .gnome2 and .gnome2_private in HOME, but I didn't create them. U11.10 did it - so they are for something necessary. Due my old graphic, Unity 2D is used. And my HOME in encrypted - if it's related, I do not know. As I have read in Bug reports, delete this files may not help and can cause other problems.  So - it is problem in U11.10 itself, not in my actions.

Comment: ------ tests: a/ if I rename login. keyring in ~/.gnome2/keyrings I get from U1 error: Authentication failed (with correct email/pass of course) -------- b/ if I rename whole ~/.gnome2 then after enter email/passw in U1 I get popup for new password for new created keyring, but after doing that I get from U1 error message: "The user canceled a prompt." (on the U1 login window again). ----------------- so - all is wrong!

Comment: If I rename the /.gnome2, then after log off -> log in is it created again (with login.keyring). If I try then U1, then I get again the ------- Method "CreateItem" with signature "a{sv}(oayay)b" on interface "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" doesn't exist ------ error message on U1 login screen.

Comment: Interesting. If you haven't already done so, could you add this to the bug thread? Possibly ... restructure it a bit.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sso-client/+bug/745540